# getting the remainder using Java

Tags: java

I can get the remainder when dividing a number, but if I were to divide 306 by 100.
e.g.
306 / 100 = 3

but if I goto find the remained by the % operator, I want to get 06 back, for example

desired

306 % 100 = 06

what actually happens

306 % 100 = 6

is there a way to get around this so that two digits are return instead of the one?

Answer (score 13):

You're getting a *number* back. 6 and 06 are the same value. An `int` (and similar types) don't have any concept of leading digits.

If you want to *format* the number in a particular way, when you convert it to a string (which is the only place this would matter) then that's simply a matter of choosing the right formatting code. Do you *always* want two digits? Use a format of "00" with [`DecimalFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html).

```
import java.text.*;

class Test {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        NumberFormat format = new DecimalFormat("00");
        int value = 6;
        System.out.println(format.format(value)); // 06
    }
}
```

(Or use `String.format`, or some other way of formatting. The important point is that the number 6 is just a number; separate the number from its textual representation in your mind.)

Answer (score 2):

This is just a matter of formatting the number. See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html).

Answer (score 1):

Split it into two parts; first get the mathematically correct answer `6`, and then present it any way you want.  If you want always two digits, you could use:

```
int x = 306 % 100;
System.out.format("%02d", x);
```

Comment: Awesome, can't believe I didn't know that existed; I think I'm usually doing this in the context of log4j, where I use `LOG.debug(String.format(...));` a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Actually for any computer language, a single digit integer number doesn't need a leading zero. You will never get this as output in any language..

However, if you want it to get printed like this, you can format your value accordingly: -

```
System.out.format("%02d", 6);
```

- First 0 denote that you want to pad your number with `ZEROs`, and the 2nd value (2) denotes how many 0's you want..

Answer (score 0):

I this 6 and 06 is just the same value, but still if you want to get the value as 6, then try this..

```
NumberFormat df = new DecimalFormat("00");
System.out.println(df.format(6));
```